# Fabry-Perot interference pattern at non-normal incidence

Tags: optics, interferometry

I'm confused about exactly how the interference happens. The original beam (at the bottom) comes in at an angle, and multiple reflected rays come out of the second mirror. But those rays are spatially offset from the original ray, so how can they interfere?

In some sketches I've seen, there's a lens after the second mirror to bring all parallel beams together, is that how they can interfere? But I've also seen videos of this experiment where no lens is used, and yet there's still interference pattern. How does that work?

[image]

Comment: rays do not interfere, waves (wavefronts) do

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of @hyportnex suggests, ray optics is not always suitable for investigating interference effects. An optical beam always has a finite width. If the offsets, caused by the incident angle, is small compared to the size of the beam, the different beams produced at the back will overlap, allowing them to interfere.